# Is there any way to change the default shortcuts for default Windows programs?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 in Portuguese and honestly, after over 13 years using computers, I still bang my head into the wall with the default shortcuts.

Just to showcase the madness:

Every program uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything. The Portuguese version uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is used to open a new tab, but Portuguese IE uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
Normally programs use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save, while the default on Portuguese is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

I'm honestly tired of this and it really hurts usability especially on Windows Explorer. Is there **any** way to put decent shortcuts into those programs?

Comment: Shortcuts are localized as well depending on the Portuguese words used. You can possibly create a massive AutoHotkey script that has program-specific overrides, but honestly if you feel more comfortable with the English version's shortcuts then that's the version you'll have to stick to.

Comment: @Karan Actually, I don't feel confortable with the English version. But the shortcuts are really important. I know they derivate from language to language, but this is pure madness! If I mistakenly press the wrong shortcut in the wrong window, I will lose a lot of work.

Comment: Well unfortunately for you you're comfortable with the English shortcuts but not the language version itself. I'm sure other Portuguese users appreciate the Portuguese shortcuts. I don't know of any acceptable workaround but let's see, perhaps someone else does.

Comment: @Karan I highly doubt it. Every client I've worked with also complains about the shortcuts. Probably the only way is re-compiling Windows itself.

Comment: For this very reason I have come to REFUSE to use anything but English-language installations of any software. Another HORRIBBLE example is the translation of function names in Excel and localization of function PARAMETERS; e.g. for Swedish =TEXT(date,"ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD") replaces the English version TEXT(date,"YYYY-MM-DD"), the English CONCATENATE() is SAMMANFOGA() and so on.

Comment: @Hannu That bothers me a lot. I'm trying to find the `DATE.VALUE()` function, when in Portuguese it is `VALOR.DATA()` (the names are swapped). Also, the support in Portuguese is written in some butchered Brazillian-like attempt of Portuguese. (Except on Windows, there the translation is either great or idiotic.)

Answer (score 0):

For all I know the key shortcuts depend on your keyboard layout. What you need to do is create [your own keyboard layout](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339).

Comment: I doubt that this is going to work. But I will take a look. I can't really test it right now, since I'm at work.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'm not so sure either since I only have Linux machines and can't test it myself. Give it a try and report back

Comment: I will, but only after 1PM UTC+00:00.